# Creating model methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I want to create a method which will give me the user's full name.

the user has a first_name and a sur_name attribute.

I am trying to do something like

```
def fullname
  "#{self.first_name} #{self.sure_name}"
end
```

but it gives me a method missing error when I try to do `@user.fullname`

am I missing something?

Comment: show a full model code, not only method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: your method calls *sure* name (with an "e"), and you want *sur* name (without an "e").